# Loading XGBoost Model: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.preprocessing._label'

Tags: pickle, xgboost

I'm having issues loading a pretrained xgboost model using the following code:

```
xgb_model = pickle.load(open('churnfinalunscaled.pickle.dat', 'rb'))
```

And when I do that, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-31e7f426e19e> in <module>()
----> 1 xgb_model = pickle.load(open('churnfinalunscaled.pickle.dat', 'rb'))

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.preprocessing._label'
```

I haven't seen anything online so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am running into the same issue. The strange things is that, when I tried to unpickle the same file on a Mac, it runs okay, however, when I try to unpickle the same file on a Linux (Debian GNU/Linux 9), I run into the same error as you did...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue. Simply update `scikit-learn` from 0.21.3 to 0.22.0 seems to solve the issue. Along the way I have to update my `pandas` version to 0.25.2 as well.

The cue is provided in this link: https://www.gitmemory.com/vruusmann, where it states:

*During Scikit-Learn version upgrade from 0.21.X to 0.22.X many modules were renamed (typically, by prepending an underscore character to the module name). For example, `sklearn.preprocessing.label.LabelEncoder` became `sklearn.preprocessing._label.LabelEncoder`.*

Comment: My `pandas` version is `1.2.3`, but I have the same problem

Comment: @EgoPingvina I had the same issue and solved it with upgrading xgboost library (to version 1.4.0)